# Set state with a value from loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looping through some data:

```
  const [var, setVar] = useState('');
  const us =  cars.map(i => {
    let myCar = cars.find(u => u.m === i.k);
    if (myCar.id === data.key) {
      return (myCar.name)
    }
  });
  setVar(us);
```

I know that is not good to `setVar` inside the loop, and I tried to set it outside the loop, but I get too many renders. Should I set it inside useEffect or not?

Comment: More context is needed, if what you provided is your component, you'll end up with an infinite loop because each time the components renders, it re-renders because you call `setVar`, i think you should use `useEffect` so the component is rendered only once, or create the array and pass it as the initial state like `const [var, setVar] = useState(us)`

Comment: Explain what you want to achive

Comment: @Joe Lloyd, i want to set the state with the result from loop

Comment: you've literally already done that above.

Comment: @Joe Lloyd, I get many renders

Comment: `const [var, setVar] = useState('');` will give you an error `unexpected token: var`. If you have an issue with code than please produce code that shows that issue.

Answer (score 2):

what about :

```
const [var, setVar] = useState(
  cars.map(i => {
    let myCar = cars.find(u => u.m === i.k);
    if (myCar.id === data.key) {
      return (myCar.name)
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a function to useState, this function will only be run first time component is rendered. Any cpu intensive task or time consuming task should be performed this way to initialize the state:

```js
const [var, setVar] = useState(() => 
  cars.map(i => {
    let myCar = cars.find(u => u.m === i.k);
    if (myCar.id === data.key) {
      return (myCar.name)
    }
  })
);
```